# Powershell - WMI error via remote connection

Tags: powershell, variables, wmi, export-to-csv, pscustomobject

I wrote script in powershell, scrips collects info about status of some system services, for example DHCP service on remote hosts. Sometimes there is a problem with connection to the remote hosts and collect info from WMI.
The WMI command below:

```
$DHCP = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $server 2>>$logerror2 | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -eq "dhcp"}
```

I created object with two properties:

```
              [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
              ServerName = $server
              DHCP = $DHCP.State
              }
```

The output is directed to the .csv file, content of the file looks like this:

```
"ServerName","DHCP"
"srv1","Running"
"srv2",,
"srv3",,
```

On hosts named "srv2" and "srv3" there is a problem with connection and gathering info from remote hosts WMI. I would like instead of blank space to give some info, for example "WMI Problem", and the content of the file should looks like this:

```
"ServerName","DHCP"
"srv1","Running"
"srv2",WMI Problem,
"srv3",WMI Problem,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should be ok:

```
## Clear the Error variable incase the last server had an error ##
if ($error)
{
    $error.clear()
}

## Attempt to do the WMI command ##
try
{
    $DHCP = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $server -erroraction stop | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "dhcp"}
}
Catch
{
    $errormsg = $_.Exception.Message
}

## If the WMI command errored then do this ##
if ($error)
{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    ServerName = $server
    DHCP = $errormsg
    }
}

## If the WMI command was successful do this ##
Else
{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    ServerName = $server
    DHCP = $DHCP.State
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a page from @Dizzy's answer.

```
$CSV = Foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
{
    $ServerObj = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        ServerName = $server
        DHCP = $null
    }

    ## Attempt to do the WMI command ##
    try
    {
        $DHCP = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $server -erroraction stop | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "dhcp"}
        [String]$ServerObj.DHCP = $DHCP.State
    }
    Catch
    {
        $errormsg = $_.Exception.Message
        [String]$ServerObj.DHCP = $errormsg
    }
    $ServerObj
}
$CSV | Export-Csv .\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```